# Flicker photo Sets not showing in PyroCMS project using Flicker gallery add on

Tags: php, codeigniter, flicker, pyrocms

I uploaded photos to the Flickr account. On next morning I expected the album to have uploaded overnight as per normal. Unfortunately not only did the Album not upload overnight all of the other albums have disappeared. I have checked Flickr and the albums are there under our Flickr account but it doesn't seem to be transferring to our intranet. I've this project in codeigniter.

> Just read from file that the project is built on PyroCMS.

not able to post the picture but in my admin panel (No photo sets have been Found ) is shown and hence on the front end. Is there any issue with the flicker api terms or something going wrong on my end i.e with code as i did not modify any thing.
Any help is appreciated as i am not an expert programmer.
Here is what i get on admin panel and hence on the front end
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Long conversation with the Author of Plugin here how i am able to solve the problem.

If you look in the library folder for the module and find the

> FLickr_API.php

file you will need to change the

> API_REST_URL

(constant defiend)at the top.
Please change it from **http** to **https**.

> Add this to the curl options on line 670

```
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

This will solve the problem, as it removes the check for verifying the SSL Certificate which generates error.